# dog's-eye view -- meaning

Tags: meaning

Example ([NASA's Curiosity Rover Eyes Weird Rock On Mars](http://www.space.com/30062-mars-rover-curiosity-weird-rock.html)):

> "We found an outcrop named Missoula where the two rock types came together, but it was quite small and close to the ground," Curiosity project scientist Ashwin Vasavada, of NASA's Jet Propulsion Laboratory in Pasadena, California, said in the same statement. "We used the robotic arm to capture a **dog's-eye view** with the MAHLI [Mars Hand Lens Imager] camera, getting our nose right in there."

How do you understand this phrase?

Comment: "...but it was quite small and close to the ground".

Comment: The machine is known as a *rover* (which is a common name for dogs).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a common construction, though we don't usually use "dog".

"[bird's-eye view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird%27s-eye_view)"

> A bird's-eye view is an elevated view of an object from above, with a perspective as though the observer were a bird, often used in the making of blueprints, floor plans and maps.

[image: Bird's-eye View]

Image from [here](http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2013/01/05/article-2257487-16C11976000005DC-337_964x889.jpg).

"bug's-eye view" or "[worm's-eye view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worm%27s-eye_view)"

> A worm's-eye view is a view of an object from below, as though the observer were a worm; the opposite of a bird's-eye view. A worm's eye view is used commonly for third perspective, with one vanishing point on top, one on the left, and one on the right.

[image: Bug's-eye view]

Image from [here](http://bloximages.newyork1.vip.townnews.com/timesonline.com/content/tncms/assets/v3/editorial/a/d2/ad2d6ba0-54bf-11e0-ad85-0017a4a78c22/4d8900f0b284e.image.jpg).

So, knowing these two (three) common terms, you should be able to guess that a "dog's-eye view" is a view from the point of view of a dog, about one or two feet off the ground.

[image: Dog's-eye view]

Image from [here](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-e82_V7Zmf6o/Tj7B-IMbTrI/AAAAAAAAC7s/UGsoDchVYSw/s1600/dogs_eye_view_of_the_city_2_by_morgan_obrien_blog.jpg)

Comment: Actually, your original first image was a God's-eye view. A bird's-eye view normally refers to an image taken from above in perspective, but God's-eye is strictly top-down. [Here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/11/Paris_moderne._Les_Tuileries%2C_le_Louvre%2C_et_la_rue_de_Rivoli%2C_vue_prise_du_Jardin_des_Tuileries.jpg) is an example of a bird's-eye drawing.

Comment: I'm going to say that God's-eye view must be colloquial, because I've lived all over the eastern US and I've never heard that term before. It's obvious what it means, but I have only ever heard "bird's-eye view" for a top-down perspective.

Comment: @TBridges42: I'm in the middle.  I've never seen "god's-eye" used, but "bird's-eye" always refers to one from a high point looking outwards, not straight down.  I've never seen "worm's eye" used, either.

Comment: @CrazyEyes I've never heard the term "God's-eye view". I've changed the image but the example is arguably unnecessary, since the OP is strictly curious about "dog's-eye".

Comment: @jamesqf I'd never heard of "worm's-eye view", either, but it was linked from the "bird's-eye view" Wikipedia page, so I included it, as Wikipedia doesn't have a page for "bug's-eye view".

Comment: @TBridges42 and Catija: I've heard God's-eye view used quite a few times, but then again I play and read a lot about video games, where camera perspective is often an important thing.

Comment: I'm used to video games using technical terms--top down vs isometric, for example. Regardless, they are all idioms, so there is really no right or wrong outside of a specific context.

Comment: I've often heard the term "thirty thousand foot view", to suggest the view from an airplane, and sometimes "fifty thousand foot view," either to suggest something a [little higher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_business_and_management_terms#Nouns), or else just because it's a more nicely rounded number. Those terms are higher than a bird, but not as high as God, and perhaps less offensive to an atheist ;^)

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, they placed the camera only a foot or two off the ground, so it is getting the same view that a dog would. It also sounds like they got very close, as a dog would when sniffing something.